# How to create VSCode syntax highlighting config for YAML strings

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, vscode-extensions

I’m looking for the same thing as Markdown code blocks syntax highlighting, but for YAML string values mapped to specific keys.

I’d like to create a syntax highlighting configuration for my own file extension, let’s say `.foo`.

The format of `.foo` files is the same as YAML, except that I want certain keys to contain string values that, when opened in vscode, are highlighted using the syntax highlighting config for a different language. This is the same as if I opened a Markdown file and started writing a code block for a different language.

For example, in the snippet below,

```yaml
bar: |
  ## My Heading
  
  - [ ] item
baz: This is an ordinary string.
```

The string stored in `bar` would use syntax highlighting for Markdown (or RMarkdown), but the string mapped to `baz` would be highlighted as a string, no different from the behavior I would get by opening a YAML file.
The non-YAML highlighting would be applied to `bar`, but not `baz`, whether or not I use a multiline string.

I don’t want to apply this syntax highlighting to all YAML files; ideally, I would have a separate syntax highlighting extension specifically for my `.foo` extension, but based on the YAML highlighting.

I don’t need to be able to specify which language the strings use from within a given `.foo` file, but I would like to be able to select which keys’ string values are highlighted using a certain language in the syntax highlighting configuration for all `.foo` files.

I've looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336796/custom-syntax-highlighting-for-certain-yaml-fields-with-vscode) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71221939/vscode-highlight-javscript-code-in-yaml-strings), but I'm having trouble getting [injection grammars](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#injection-grammars) to work, especially when it comes to tying the grammar to a specific key.

Comment: perhaps there's a way to use the [embedded language](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/embedded-languages) feature instead of injection grammars? not sure.

Answer (score 2):

To implement what you want to achieve, you'll need to create a new language extension in Visual Studio Code, and utilize VS Code's Language Injection functionality. This is a nontrivial task, so I'll give a high-level outline of the steps involved:

Create a VS Code Extension: You'll first need to set up a new extension. Microsoft provides an excellent guide on how to get started with https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension here. For your use case, you'll be creating a new language extension.

Define Your New Language: Once you've created your extension, you'll need to define your new language (in this case, the '.foo' language). You do this by creating a language configuration file. More details can be found https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide . You'll want to specify that your language is based on YAML.

Define Your Injection Grammar: Next, you'll need to define your injection grammar. This is the tricky part. Essentially, what you'll be doing is specifying that certain keys in your '.foo' files should be highlighted as if they were written in a different language (in your case, Markdown). You can read more about how to do this https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#injection-grammars. Essentially, what you're doing is specifying a pattern that VS Code will look for (in your case, the 'bar:' key), and then providing the scope of the language that should be injected at that point (in your case, 'text.html.markdown').

Here's a simplified example of what your injection grammar might look like:

```
{
    "fileTypes": [],
    "injectionSelector": "L:yaml",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "match": "(bar):\\s*$",
            "captures": {
                "1": { "name": "entity.name.tag.yaml" }
            }
        },
        {
            "include": "text.html.markdown"
        }
    ],
    "scopeName": "markdown.yaml"
}
```

Test Your Extension: Once you've defined your injection grammar, you'll want to test your extension to make sure it's working correctly. You can do this by running the extension in the Extension Development Host window. You should see that when you open a '.foo' file, the keys you specified are highlighted as if they were written in the injected language.

Please note that the whole process is a bit complex and requires a deep understanding of regular expressions and syntax highlighting in VS Code. You might need to refine the injection grammar definition to fit your needs.

Comment: I tried your solution and ran into a few issues. There's no "new language extension" option when I run `yo code`. I tried "New Langauge Support", and it doesn't ask me to specify what language to base my extension on. I see the injection grammar provided, but in which file do I put this? Assuming I can start with a language extension based on YAML, do I put it in `foo.tmLanguage.json`, or `packages.json`?